# using continious values for hyperparameters in grid search (ANN)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, grid-search

I'm trying to tune hyperparameters in a neural network (regression problem), and i have few questions:

1. which order should i use in automatic optimisation methods (grid , random , bayesian , genetics, ...)
2. i started with grid search to get an idea of the learning and i know
   grid give us optimal result but its a time consuming , i dont have problem with the time so i want to try the best search space but i  only know how to choose a discret values for a hyperparameter and i
   dont know how to give a certain hyperparameter a continious values to    test ,ex: i want to test the epoch values between (500 and 10000) with a step of 200 , and for the learning rate between
   0.001 and 0.9,so how can i achieve that in grid search or any other optimisation method in ANN.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: it is about programming , i dont know if keras support this option or not or if there is other solutions like defining a custom func or using other libraries .

Comment: Sorry, but Keras does not even support anything like this; let alone that Keras is nowhere mentioned in the question (or the tags), nor any other programming framework (or language) for that matter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should have a look to [Tune](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://docs.ray.io/en/master/tune/index.html&ved=2ahUKEwjus9m4g7PvAhWiDmMBHVynDq8QFjAAegQIBhAC&usg=AOvVaw2ZA4uWltA9AcWxoDR3qIJx), which is based on Ray. It offers several powerful algorithms to tune both continuous and discrete parameters using grid search or more advanced strategies such as population-based evolution strategies. Plus, it is rather easy to use.